# delete row that is not rendered in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table where I have checkboxes as the first column so I can select and delete all the rows I want.

To select the rows, I am using the checkbox click event to record the selected cId (not the datatable row id) and storing in an array.

I have a delete button to delete all the selected rows. I am using the following code in the click event to delete the selected rows.

```
 $.each(selectedChks, function (index, cId){
                checkbox = $("#chk-"+cId);
                target_row=$(checkbox).closest("tr")[0];
                oDataTable.fnDeleteRow(target_row, null, false);
    });
    oDataTable.fnDraw();
```

It seems to work fine on the rows that are rendered. I can delete multiple rows in the rendered table.

But if I selected the rows are in different pages, the above code fails with the error TypeError: s[b] is undefined.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the HTML?   You'll get more help if you make a jsFiddle.

Comment: What do you mean by "selected rows are in different pages"?

Comment: @Kevin, Consider I have 10 pages in the datatables. I checked one checkbox on page1 and checked one more in page3 and tried to delete the selected rows from the selectedChks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are having problems deleting any rows that are hidden due to paging being enabled.

I setup a fiddle, and it doesn't look like you can delete rows that are not in the current page.  There are way around that, though.

Here is a [fiddle of a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/85/).

```
/* Init the table */
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( ),
    selectedChks = ['1', '4', '8', '10', '14', '19'];

/* Add a click handler for the delete row */
$('#delete').click( function() {
    //revert table
    oTable.fnDestroy();
    $.each(selectedChks, function (index, cId)
    {
        //now that we reverted the table, lets just use jQuery to remove the row
        $("#chk-"+cId).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    //initialize new table, so that row counts etc are updated
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

Comment: I tried this but the $checkbox.parents('tr').first().get(0) returns undefined for the rows that are not in the current rendered page. javascript throws error while calculating for rownum. I also tried the target_row = $(checkbox).closest("tr")[0] but the same problem. It can identify the rows in the current rendered page but not any other page.

Comment: @VijayKalidindi Take a look at this fiddle I just posted, one way of doing it is to revert the table, remove rows then initialize the table.